# C++ Regex getting all match's on line

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

When reading line by line i call this function on each line looking for function calls(names).  I use this function to match the any valid characters a-z 0-9 and _ with '('.  My problem is i do not understand fully the c++ style regex and how to get it to look through the entire line for possible matches?.  This regex is simple and strait forward just does not work as expected but im learning this is the c++ norm.

```
void readCallbacks(const std::string lines)
{
  std::string regxString = "[a-z0-9]+\(";
  regex regx(regxString, std::regex_constants::icase);
  smatch result;

  if(regex_search(lines.begin(), lines.end(), result, regx, std::regex_constants::match_not_bol))
  {
    cout << result.str() << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash or use a raw string literal:

```
std::regex pattern("[a-z0-9]+\\(", std::regex_constants::icase);
//                           ^^

std::regex pattern(R"([a-z0-9]+\()", std::regex_constants::icase);
//                 ###^^^^^^^^^^^##
```

Also, your character range doesn't contain the desired underscore (`_`).